# Signed Integer to Unsigned Integer & DWORD Conversion

Tags: c#

I have a Win32 API call which returns a signed 32bit integer value (-2147022987).

In Windows Calculator (in Programmer View `Alt-3`) mode set to `Dec` and `Dword` if I enter the value of -2147022987 and then switch the mode to `Word` I get 1909.  Am I understanding correctly that 1909 is a representation of ONE of the two `Word`s contained in the `DWord`? Is this value considered the low order `Dword` or the high order `Dword`?

How I programmatically do this conversion in C# so I can match the value against the enum type defined below?

```
public enum LogonError : ushort
{
    LogonSuccessful = 0,
    PasswordMustChange = 1907,
    NoSuchUser = 1317,
    LogonFailure = 1326,
    AccountRestriction = 1327,
    AccountDisabled = 1331,
    InvalidLogonHours = 1328,
    NoLogonServers = 1311,
    InvalidWorkstation = 1329,
    AccountLockedOut = 1909,
    AccountExpired = 1793,
    PasswordExpired = 1330
}
```

Comment: `LogonError err = unchecked((LogonError)(-2147022987));`

Comment: OR `int errcode = -2147022987; LogonError err = (LogonError)errcode;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `&` (bitwise AND) operator as follows:

```
int i = -2147022987;
LogonError err = (LogonError)(i & 0xffff);  // 1909
```

Comment: I ended up using L.B's approach in the comments to he question, but this answer also works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are declaring your external API call like this:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
```

you can get the error code with this function:

```
int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

you may need to change your enum to `int` and this only works when using `SetLastError = true`

Comment: Someone downvoted-I'm upvoting-while it makes an assumption the `enum` is being used with `LogonUser` for impersonation & doesn't answer how to convert a DWORD to ushort, it brings up a valid way to get back the error code.